# Catch request.path with dynamic urls

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In flask, i need to add a class when the request.path match a condition.

My problem is that request.path will be like

```
/users/history/job/john
/users/history/job/pedro
/users/history/role/fabio
/users/history/role/pedro
...
```

How can i catch that cases? This will not work due the dynamic part of url. There is any type of wildcards?

```
{% if request.path == "/users/history/job" %}active{% endif %}>
{% if request.path == "/users/history/role" %}active{% endif %}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{% if "/users/history/job/" in request.path %}active{% endif %}>
{% if "/users/history/role/" in request.path %}active{% endif %}>
```